# Java: round to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down)

Tags: java, rounding

I need to round a number to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down). For example, here are the list of numbers and the number next to it that it needs to round up/down to.

```
12.5  10
62.1  60
68.3  70
74.5  75
80.7  80
```

Numbers will only be positive.

Comment: What do you want to happen to midpoints (e.g. 12.5)?

Comment: @AndroidDev if `12.5 would be 10` then unfortunately my answer does not work. In this case you'd have to apply the idea of Achintya

Answer (score 112, accepted):

haven't tested it, but `5*(Math.round(f/5));` should work

Comment: OK, I was really close. Your solution is the same as koljaTM. I'm not sure who gets the checkmark. His shows 0 and yours shows 8 but the times are the same. Who is suppose to get the checkmark?

Comment: This is not working... 
Eg - 75.5 should round off to 76

but it doesn't

Comment: @MilindaBandara why do you think 75.5 should return 76? According to the examples the OP gave, it should return 75

Comment: Remember this is not a foolproof solution! In case of very large values you will run into problems with double's precision.

Answer (score 47):

Nearest Multiple of 5
for Upper value

```
5*(Math.ceil(Math.abs(number/5)));
```

for Lower Value

```
5*(Math.floor(Math.abs(number/5)));
```

it gives Positive value only.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double num = 67.5;
    if (num % 5 == 0)
        System.out.println("OK");
    else if (num % 5 < 2.5)
        num = num - num % 5;
    else
        num = num + (5 - num % 5);
    System.out.println(num);

}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
return round((number/5))*5;
```

Answer (score 5):

Gefei's solution is working, but I had to convert explicitly to double like this: `5*(Math.round((double)f/5))`

Answer (score 3):

In case you have an integer as input, otherwise the accepted answer will round it to down.

```
int value = 37;
value = (int) ( Math.round( value / 5.0 ) * 5.0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many other solutions on this page, but I believe this is the most concise one.

To find the closest multiple of x for a given number,

let x be the multiple and num be the given number:

```
// The closest multiple of x <= num
int multipleOfX = x * ( num / x );
```

In your case:

```
int multipleOf5 = 5 * ( num / 5 );
```

Comment: Please note that this only returns your rounded down answer.