# Division to yield result in multiples of hundred or thousand etc

Tags: java, integer-division

I have a variable set in my program:

```
int weekInterval = 100;
```

I have the following function:

```
public void weeksToNotify(int weeks, String date){
        Date dt = Convert(date); 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        cal.setTime(dt); 
        weekSpecial = weekInterval*(1+(weeks/weekInterval)); 
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, (weekSpecial*7));
        dateWeekReg = cal.getTime();
    }
```

The parameters to this function are:

`int weeks: The current age in weeks for the person/event/thing.`

`String date: The date of birth of the person/event/thing.`

Now upon execution of this function the variable weekSpecial has the desired value, but I want to round off this value. So for example if the weekSpecial variable has the value 150 I want 200 as the result, if it has a value of 23400 I want only 23000 etc. I am not looking for a precise answer, I want to learn how to solve this. SO a pointer or a hint/ Algo will do for me. Thanks :)

Comment: what's the scale for rounding? eg. `150->100`, `23500->23000` both are rounding at different scales. The former at 100's place and the latter at 1000's place.

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake, the regular mathematical rules apply here - so 150 can become 200 and 140 becomes 100.

Comment: This post ought to help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down

Comment: Can you clarify how to choose the number of significant figures to round to?  Why do we round 150 to 1 significant figure, but 23400 to 2 significant figures?

Comment: @user2822178-I think my answer helps you solve your problematic sitution.Please check and reply!

Comment: Working on it, will let you know shortly :)

Comment: You should also clarify how you specify the rounding. For example, if 150 is to become 200, why does 23400 have to become 23000? Apparently, if you had 23150 you would expect to round it to 23000 and not 23200.

Comment: Yes exactly, I think it was not too clear in the question description -- I want general rules of rounding off to apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first value (`150`), you can try setting

`weekSpecial = weekSpecial/100 * 100`

after the calculation of the `weekSpecial` parameter.

Integer division in `Java` drops the decimal part, so first dividing and then multiplying by `100` should give you what you asked.

Of course, the calculation can be integrated in one statement, e.g.

```
weekSpecial = (weekInterval*(1+(weeks/weekInterval)) / 100) * 100;
```

This works if the rounding you need is 2 digits (e.g., from `150` to `100`), otherwise you need to divide and multiply by `10 ^ n`, where `n` is the number of digits you need rounded off (in the case of 150, `n = 2`).

So, for `23500` the multiplication should be `23500/1000 * 1000`.

In general, assuming that you know `n`, the answer is

```
double factor = Math.pow(10, n);
weekSpecial = (int)(Math.round(weekSpecial/factor * factor));
```

Comment: @PNS-Your answer doesn;t satisfy his purpose!

Comment: @shekharsuman If you're going to make a statement like that you really need to explain *how* and *why* it doesn't satisfy their purpose. Right now your comment is pointless noise.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist-The reason being (23500/100)*100=23500.Hence,dividing by 100 won't work.Moreover,as per the OP,he needs the result to be truncated!

Comment: I was still editing when the comments were added. See the answer now.

Comment: Can you demonstrate a dry run of this code? For the number 150?

Comment: Just put the two lines of code with the factor parameter immediately after the calculation of weekSpecial, with n = 2, and run it.

Answer (score 3):

From what it seems you are looking for an algorithm that starts rounding accorging to the second character from the left.

since you don't want an answer I will hint that if you divide the value of `weekSpecial` by 10 (with a counter) until the value is less than 100 and then divide by 100 and use the `Round` function, and finally multiply by 10^(2 + counter) you should be able to get the rounded number you're looking for.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A possible algorithm for this can go like this :-

Check the length of your `WeekSpecial` variable(first converting to `String` and then applying `int length()` method).

See,if WeekSpecial Variable is in range of 100's--->then do `weekSpecial = weekSpecial/100 * 100`.

If WeekSpecial Variable is in range of 1000's--->then do `weekSpecial = weekSpecial/1000 * 1000`.

Similarly,if WeekSpecial Variable is in the range of 10^n,---> then do `weekSpecial=(weekSpecial/10^n)*10^n`.

Also,if you round off the value to nearest power 10^n go as shown below :-

> Say,160-->200------(1.0*160/100)=1.6.Apply,Math.round(1.6)=2. and
>   after rounding,multiply it by 10^n,i.e.,100 here,you'll get 200 here.I
>   hope I am clear!

Probably,this could help you by rounding off the value!

Comment: +1, we made the same clarification simultaneously. :-)

Comment: @PNS-Thanks,I also wrote the same.

Comment: Say I have the number 150. Now I implement (150/100)*100. That is(1.5)*100 that is 150? Sorry maybe I am asking a dumb question but I am not able to understand how this works.

Comment: No,in Java,the integer division yields only integer result!
Please revise your basic operator section. Here,150/100 will return 1 and after multiplying 1*100 you get 100;

Comment: Whoooop! My bad! But then how is it justified for 160?

Comment: I have upvoted you already and will accept the answer, as soon as it satisfies my condition. Please elaborate on how 160 will become 200 using your scheme.

Comment: Well,if you want to achieve that,do this :-
(1.0)*(160/100)=1.6.Apply,Math.round(1.6)=2.
and after rounding,multiply it by 10^n,i.e.,100 here,you'll get 200 here.I hope I am clear!

Comment: @user2822178-Sorry,check the anser updated! (1.0*160/100)=1.6--> Not,(1.0)*(160/100)=2//it will be 1.0 only!

Answer (score 2):

You could use  Math.round. This rounds your number to the nearest value, above or below your integer.  The below example rounds to the nearest 100.

```
int weekInterval;

System.out.println (Math.round(weekInterval/100.00)*100);
```

If you want to round to the nearest 1000, simply divide/multiply by 1000.