# Round time by seconds

Tags: java, date, rounding, jodatime

In my Java project I want round Date time seconds which is divided by 5.

```
I have got   -   I want 
 12:00:01    -  12:00:00
 12:00:04    -  12:00:05
 12:00:06    -  12:00:05
 12:00:07    -  12:00:05
 12:00:08    -  12:00:10
 ...
 12:00:58    -  12:01:00
```

Date object contain date for example: `Fri May 12 12:00:03 CEST 2017` 
and I want round seconds to modulo 5. I want achieve Date object with rounded seconds.

How can I do this using simple math or `Joda` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You see, this is not a "you drop requirements we drop code" service.

Comment: I want round time to every 5 seconds.

Comment: Its not possible out of the box, you have to do the rounding yourself, but this is more or less a simple switch case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: round to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down)

Comment: I understand what you want. I am asking you what you **tried** to get there yourself before writing this question.

Comment: I do not tried, do not have idea how to do it - so asking.

Comment: JodaTime has indeed rounding features, but not such special rounding features of exactly the type you want. So a Joda solution would not be easier than what you have accepted based on `java.time`-package in Java-8. For an easier and shorter solution, you might also have a look at my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which offers such specialized rounding methods, see this [gist-example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/3dd558dafeacc4e882b263955108ab08).

Comment: @Berger No, not a duplicate [of that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down). There is much more to date-time handling than a single integer number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a suggestion:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Before rounding: " + time);
    int secondsSinceLastWhole5 = time.getSecond() % 5;
    if (secondsSinceLastWhole5 >= 3) { // round up
        time = time.plusSeconds(5 - secondsSinceLastWhole5);
    } else { // round down
        time = time.minusSeconds(secondsSinceLastWhole5);
    }
    System.out.println("After rounding: " + time);
```

Output examples:

```
Before rounding: 14:46:33
After rounding: 14:46:35

Before rounding: 14:47:37
After rounding: 14:47:35
```

The `% 5` (modulo 5) operation will give us the number of seconds since the last whole 5 seconds on the clock, as a number in the interval 0 through 4. Using that we know which way to round.

I am using `java.time.LocalTime`. It’s the recommended class for times without an explicit time zone today.

Comment: It works well :) There is no Joda method to round it ? It must be done manually ?

Comment: I should probably have made clear from the start I am using `java.time`, not JodaTime. Not surprised the class is called the same. You can truncate a `java.time.LocalTime` to a whole time unit as I do in the first code line, but not to whole 5 seconds. I don’t know about JodaTime’s version.

Comment: Any particular reason you may prefer JodaTime over `java.time`? Today the [JodaTime home page](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).”

Comment: The impression I get from what I read is that `java.time` is generally at least as good, though there are corner cases where JodaTime offers functions that are not (yet) in `java.time`. If you are not yet using Java 8 (or later), you can get the classes in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (that’s ThreeTen for JSR-310).

Comment: Or easier in my lib Time4J: `LocalTime rounded = PlainTime.from(time).with(SECOND_OF_MINUTE.roundedHalf(5)).toTemporalAccessor();`

Comment: @MenoHochschild, if you want to bother posting that as an answer, I shall be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Just as supplement to the correct answer of Ole V.V:

As far as I know (but other might correct me), **Joda-Time** offers [rounding features](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#roundHalfEvenCopy--) but not of the type the OP wants, namely in configurable step widths (here: 5 seconds). So I suspect that a Joda solution would be very similar to that given by @Ole which is based on Java-8.

My time library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) has some more rounding features without any need to think so much about the rounding math as following code demonstrates:

```
import net.time4j.ClockUnit;
import net.time4j.PlainTime;

import net.time4j.format.expert.Iso8601Format;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import static net.time4j.PlainTime.*;

public class RoundingOfTime {

    public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
        PlainTime t1 = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_WALL_TIME.parse("12:59:57");
        PlainTime t2 = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_WALL_TIME.parse("12:59:58");

        System.out.println(t1.with(SECOND_OF_MINUTE.roundedHalf(5))); // T12:59:55
        System.out.println(t2.with(SECOND_OF_MINUTE.roundedHalf(5))); // T13

        LocalTime rounded =
            PlainTime.nowInSystemTime()
            .with(PRECISION, ClockUnit.SECONDS) // truncating subseconds
            .with(SECOND_OF_MINUTE.roundedHalf(5)) // rounding
            .toTemporalAccessor(); // conversion to java-time
        System.out.println(rounded); // 15:57:05
    }
}
```

The method [roundedHalf(int)](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/ProportionalElement.html#roundedHalf-int-) is applicable on most time elements defined in the class `PlainTime`. I welcome further enhancement proposals, maybe even finding a way to define such methods as kind of `TemporalAdjuster`.