# Make number multiple of 100 and 50 java

Tags: java, numbers

I have a number with range 0-100 ,

When the number is between

1) **1000 - 500**  - I wanted the number to be rounded to multiple of 100 i.e 837 to 800 , 922 to 900 , 659 to 600

2) **0 - 500** -  I wanted the number to be rounded to multiple of 50 i.e 478 to 450, 322 to 300 , 259 to 250

Comment: OK. So, what is your question? Have you tried anything? What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: If you have a number in the range 0–100, it will not be between 1000 - 500.

Comment: Try to create own `Round_Mode` and use `Decimal`. Other wise just use multi if-else.

Comment: I have to handle upto 50 not below that .

Comment: Post what you've written so far, along with a specific question about what you're having trouble with. Remember, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: round to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
if( number < 500 ){
    return number / 50 * 50;
} else {
    return number / 100 * 100;
}
```

This code just looks how many whole `fiftys` or `hundreds` can be placed inside your number and then multiplies the result, which then leads to your desired result.

Comment: Reason for `Math.floor` ?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik you were right java already does it internally when dividing `int` by another `int`. So `Math.floor` is not really needed