# Round decimals up to multiples of 5 with BigDecimal

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I want to round BigDecimal decimal part according to the following rules:

- `1710.10` becomes `1710.10`
- `1710.11` becomes `1710.15`
- `1710.15` becomes `1710.15`
- `1710.16` becomes `1710.20`

I tried this way `new BigDecimal("1710.11").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))`, expecting to get `1710.15` but I get `1710.11`. I also tried with Apache Math Utils and Decimal Format but no way to achieve this.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to multiply by 2, round, and then divide by 2.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. There is no way that HALF_UP is supposed to round 1710.11 to 1710.15. HALF_UP is defined as _"Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up."_, but the number you're trying to round is already rounded to two decimal position, so nothing is changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: round to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your misunderstanding

First of all setting the scale on a BigDecimal only returns a BigDecimal with a different value if your current BigDecimal has a higher scale than you specified.

For example

```
new BigDecimal("1710.113").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

returns a new BigDecimal equal to `new BigDecimal("1710.11")`

However, if you already have a scale of 2 or lower in this example, the new BigDecimal stays the same (read: equal).

`HALF_UP` simply means that a BigDecimal ending on a 5 will result in the higher value, e.g.

```
new BigDecimal("1710.115").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

returns a result equal to `new BigDecimal("1710.12")`

#### Now to your question

Since your way of "rounding" doesn't actually change the scale, I doubt there is an already existing function you could use. However, doing it by hand is actually quite simple:

```
public class QuickMathz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.10"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.11"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.15"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.16"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1135"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1635"), 2));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1675"), 2));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.10"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.11"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.15"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.16"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1135"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1635"), 3));
        System.out.println(roundToNext5(new BigDecimal("1710.1675"), 3));
    }

    public static BigDecimal roundToNext5(BigDecimal bigDecimal, int scale) {
        // Get the last digit we need to decide if we have to round to 0, 5 or 10
        int lastDigit = bigDecimal
                .movePointRight(scale)
                .remainder(BigDecimal.TEN).intValue();

        // Setting the Scale to scale - 1 to remove one more digit than we need
        // and then increase the scale to what we want
        BigDecimal result = bigDecimal
                .setScale(scale - 1, RoundingMode.DOWN)
                .setScale(scale, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);

        if (lastDigit == 0) {
            // Last digit is a 0 upscaling adds a 0
            return result;
        } else if (lastDigit <= 5) {
            // rounding up to 5
            return result.add(new BigDecimal("5").movePointLeft(scale));
        } else {
            // rounding up to 10
            return result.add(new BigDecimal("1").movePointLeft(scale - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

This class yields the output of

```
1710.10
1710.15
1710.15
1710.20
1710.15
1710.20
1710.20

1710.100
1710.110
1710.150
1710.160
1710.115
1710.165
1710.170
```

(It's neither optimized nor checked for negative values, so don't use in critical environments)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to solve this:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

class CustomRoundingTests {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
            "1710.10, 1710.10",
            "1710.11, 1710.15",
            "1710.15, 1710.15",
            "1710.16, 1710.20",
            "1710.96, 1711.00",

    })
    void testRoundToNearestFive(String input, String expected) {
        BigDecimalFiveRounded value = new BigDecimalFiveRounded(input);
        BigDecimal roundedValue = value.round();
        assertEquals(new BigDecimal(expected), roundedValue);
    }

    public static class BigDecimalFiveRounded extends BigDecimal {
        public BigDecimalFiveRounded(String val) {
            super(val);
        }

        public BigDecimal round() {
            BigDecimal fractionalPart = this.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
            BigDecimal scaledFractionalPart = fractionalPart.multiply(new BigDecimal("100"))
                    .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            int firstDigit = scaledFractionalPart.intValue() / 10;
            int secondDigit = scaledFractionalPart.intValue() % 10;

            var result = this.subtract(new BigDecimal("0." + firstDigit + secondDigit));
            if (secondDigit == 0) {
                // Nothing to do
                return this.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            } else if (secondDigit > 5) {
                firstDigit++;
                // Handle the case when we need to increase integer part
                if (firstDigit >= 10) {
                    firstDigit = 0;
                    result = result.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
                }
                secondDigit = 0;
            } else {
                secondDigit = 5;
            }

            var newFractionalPart = new BigDecimal("0." + firstDigit + secondDigit);
            return result.add(newFractionalPart).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }
    }
}
```

Test results:

```
[root]
testRoundToNearestFive(String, String)
[1] input=1710.10, expected=1710.10
[2] input=1710.11, expected=1710.15
[3] input=1710.15, expected=1710.15
[4] input=1710.16, expected=1710.20
[5] input=1710.96, expected=1711.00
```

Comment: Do not use images for text. Just print the results and copy in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use a `Currency` class with a minimum denomination and a `round` method:

```
public class Currency {
    private final String symbol;
    private final BigDecimal minDenomination;

    public Currency(String symbol, BigDecimal minDenomination) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.minDenomination = minDenomination;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMinDenomination() {
        return minDenomination;
    }

    public BigDecimal round(BigDecimal value, RoundingMode mode) {
        return value.divide(minDenomination)
                .setScale(0, mode)
                .multiply(minDenomination)
                .setScale(minDenomination.scale());
    }
}
```

then:

```
    String[] values = {
        "1710.10",
        "1710.11",
        "1710.15",
        "1710.16"        };
    Currency chf = new Currency("CHF", new BigDecimal("0.05"));
    for (String s: values) {
        BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(s);
        System.out.println(val + " -> " + chf.round(val, RoundingMode.UP));
    }
    System.out.println();
    Currency usd = new Currency("USD", new BigDecimal("0.01"));
    for (String s: values) {
        BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(s);
        System.out.println(val + " -> " + usd.round(val, RoundingMode.UP));
    }
```

Comment: Some values are unchanged and not what the author wanted 1710.14 -> 1710.14
1710.96 -> 1710.96

Comment: @BorislavGizdov whell, perhaps it's `RoundingMode.UP` that he needs?

Answer (score 0):

Most folks are familiar with rounding up from some fraction ending in `5`.  That would be `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` where `5` or more rounds up to the adjacent digit and down if less than `5`. Other modes are explained in detail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html).  To do what you want requires some customization.  Here I do it using a lambda which can be applied to a `scale value` and the `BigDecimal` as arguments. It extracts the whole part and fractional part and mathematically adjusts the fractional part to the requirements, returning a rounded BigDecimal.

```
 BiFunction<Integer, BigDecimal, BigDecimal> round = (scale, bigD) -> {
     bigD = bigD.movePointRight(scale-2);
     String bigDStr = bigD.toString();
     int i = bigDStr.indexOf(".");
     String save = bigDStr.substring(0,i);
     int fract = Integer.parseInt(bigDStr.substring(i+1));
     fract = (fract+4)/5*5;
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(save).append(".").append(fract);
     return new BigDecimal(sb.toString()).movePointLeft(scale-2); 
 };

String[] values = {
        "1710.10","1710.11","1710.15","1710.16","1710.10","1710.11",
        "1710.15","1710.16"
};

for (String val : values) {
    BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(val);
    System.out.printf("%.2f  ->  %.2f%n", d, round.apply(2, d));
}
```

prints

```
1710.10  ->  1710.10
1710.11  ->  1710.15
1710.15  ->  1710.15
1710.16  ->  1710.20
1710.10  ->  1710.10
1710.11  ->  1710.15
1710.15  ->  1710.15
1710.16  ->  1710.20
```

A few other examples

```
System.out.println(round.apply(3,new BigDecimal("1710.124")));
System.out.println(round.apply(4,new BigDecimal("1710.1247")));
System.out.println(round.apply(5,new BigDecimal("1710.12489")));
System.out.println(round.apply(6,new BigDecimal("1710.124542")));
```

prints

```
1710.125
1710.1250
1710.12490
1710.124545
```